# Saving a dataframe to SQL Server as a table with a given structure

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to combine pandas and sqlalchemy to save a dataframe to sql server. If I save the dataframe directly with df.to_sql, ex:

```
cirbe.to_sql("Cirbe", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, index_label=index_label)
```

it sets no variable types nor conditions to the table. If viewed in Server Management Studio, the table is a set of *(varChar, null)* columns.

sqlalchemy seems to allow a predefinition of table such as:

```
tablaCirbe = Table('Cirbe', metadata_obj,
             Column('CIF', String(20), primary_key=True),
             Column('mes', Integer, primary_key=True),
             Column('año', Integer, primary_key = True),
             Column('Entidad', String(), primary_key=True),
             Column('Operacion', String(), primary_key=True),
             Column('Tipo', Tipo, nullable=False),
             Column('NatInterv', NatInterv, nullable=False),
             Column('SolCol', SolCol),
             Column('Participantes', Integer),
             Column('Moneda', Moneda, nullable=False),
             Column('Plazo', Plazo),
             Column('GarantiaReal', GarantiaReal),
             Column('GarantiaPersonal', String()),
             Column('SituOper', SituOper),
             Column('Dispuesto', Float),
             Column('Importes', Float),
             Column('DemoraGastos', Float),
             Column('Disponible', Float),
             schema='dbo'
)
```

which includes data types, restrictions and even enumerations.

How can both elements be combined so that when the dataframe is exported to sql it keeps the datatypes and conditions? I guess there is a pretty straightforward way to do so, by I haven't found any documentation.
Thanks

Comment: Try `tablaCirbe.create(engine)` followed by `.to_sql(tablaCirbe.__tablename__, engine, if_exists="append", …)`

Comment: As suggested (I believe), I have used:

`tablaCirbe.create(engine)
cirbe.to_sql(tablaCirbe.__tablename__, con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, index_label=index_label, schema=tablaCirbe.schema)`

tableCirbe has no attribute tablename. How come? (tablaCirbe is created following the specified structure?

Comment: tableCirbe.name does exist, but it is only provides the string, the table is created in the ddbb with that same name but with none of the properties.

Comment: Okay sorry, `__tablename__` is an ORM thing. `tableCirbe.name` should work.

Comment: tableCirbe.name just gives a name to the table, but for some reason does not mean a link between tableCirbe and cirbe.to_sql. What I mean is that cirbe.to_sql does not take the properties of tableCirbe. I will keep on trying.

Comment: If `dbo` is not the default schema for your database user then maybe you need to add `schema="dbo"` to your `.to_sql()` call.

Comment: dbo is the default schema :( , but I will try anyway